# List AMIs older than x days/months

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

Does anyone know if its possible to retrieve a list of EC2 AMIs older than x months(or days) using the ec2_ami_find module? So far I've got:

```
- name: ec2 find all
  ec2_ami_find:
    owner: self
    region: us-west-1
    sort: creationDate
    sort_order: descending
  register: ec2_ami

- name: test
  set_fact:
    date: "{{lookup('pipe','date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d \"180 day ago\"')}}"
    msg: "{{ ec2_ami | json_query('results[?creationDate<`{{ date }}`]') }}"
```

However, this doesnt seem to work with me. Whatever I put in the date command(180 days, 1 day, 700 days), it retrieves the exact same list of AMI's for me.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with string interpolation and replacing the date variable in the `set_fact` directive. Here is an example, also I have used the `ec2_ami_facts` module instead of `ec2_ami_find` as `ec2_ami_find` would be deprecated soon.

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: me
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - ec2_ami_facts:
        owner: self
        region: eu-central-1
      register: ec2_ami

    - set_fact:
        filter_date: "{{ lookup('pipe','date \"+%Y-%m-%d\" -d \"180 day ago\"') }}"

    - debug: var=filter_date

    - set_fact:
        filtered_ami: "{{ ec2_ami | json_query(\"images[?creation_date<=`\" + filter_date + \"`]\") }}"

    - shell: echo "{{ filtered_ami | length }} {{ ec2_ami.images | length }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Please find the python script to list the AMIs older than X Days. Please do not forget to update your AWS credential profile value if you have multiple accounts as profiles=["default", "profile2"].

`

```
    import boto3
    from dateutil.parser import parse
    import datetime
    retention_day = "<addyour desired days here> eg. 30"
    profiles = ["default"]
    def days_old(date):
        get_date_obj = parse(date)
        date_obj = get_date_obj.replace(tzinfo=None)
        diff = datetime.datetime.now() - date_obj
        return diff.days
    
    
    def get_ami_snap_list():
        for profile in profiles:
            session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
            ec2 = session.client('ec2')
            Name=""
            Description=""
            amis = ec2.describe_images(Owners=[
                    'self'
                ])
            for ami in amis['Images']:
                try:
                    create_date = ami['CreationDate']
                    ami_id = ami['ImageId']
                    # print ami['ImageId'], ami['CreationDate']
                    day_old = days_old(create_date)
                    if day_old > retention_day:
                        # print(ami_id)
                        image = ec2.describe_images(ImageIds=[ami_id])
                        
                        for img in image['Images']:
                            Name=img['Name']
                            Description=img['Description']
    
                        print(ami_id+",",Name+",",Description+",",profile)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(ami_id + ",", Name + ",", Description + ",", profile)
    
    
    get_ami_snap_list()
```